# Vuetify validate textfield on input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

```
<v-text-field v-model='postal_code' 
  validate-on-blur
  name="postal_code"
  :maxlength="postalCodeLength(postal_code)"
  ref="postalCode"
  @input="handle(postal_code, 'postalCode')"
  :rules="postalCodeRules"
  required
  :disabled="disabledPostalCode">
</v-text-field>
```

I want the validation message to appear as soon as the user starts typing on the text field. But the validation message appears when the user leaves the textfield and starts entering data on another textfield. I think this is because of validate-on-blur but if remove validate-on-blur then the validation message appears all the time even if the user is not entering data on this field. Help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain, If you are using rules to validate, then what is the `handle` function's job?

Comment: @NehaSoni handle function is to auto-format the postal code after it is entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding multiple attributes for a validation (`maxlength`, `required`, `etc..`), You can simply add these validations in your `:rules` object, Rest will take care by the Vuetify and Vue.

If you want to handle any logics on input change, Then you can achieve that by using `@input` event and based on the validation rule passed, You can put that logic accordingly.

Here is the live demo (Just for a demo purpose I added only `required` field validation) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    name: ''
  },
  methods: {
    validateField() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.$refs.nameInput.validate()) {
          console.log('name field validation passed')
        } else {
          console.log('name field validation failed')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-text-field
    outline
    v-model="name"
    label="Enter Your Name"
    :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Name is required']"
    @input="validateField"
    ref="nameInput"
  />
</div>
```